# Understanding the reading of 川 in 品川区

Tags: kanji, readings

As of the resources I have consulted like [romajidesu](https://www.romajidesu.com/kanji/%E5%B7%9D), `川` has only one kun'yomi reading which is `kawa`.

If that is the case, why is it read as `gawa` in `品川区`?

Comment: Because it's a kun'yomi reading, and kun'yomi readings in compounds often undergo [rendaku](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese/rendaku/).